# Inspect elements in core.async/sliding-buffer in Clojure

Tags: clojure, circular-buffer, core.async, peek

How do I take a snapshot of all the values in a `sliding-buffer` channel?

I'm using the sliding buffer to store temporal measurements that I occasionally want to render the most recent (say 100) values of.

There are some circular buffer implementations making the rounds, but I'd like to leverage the core.async abstractions later.

I've tried to tap into a mult, calling (seq my-sliding-buffer) and calling `take!` on the tap, but Clojure complains that the `SlidingBuffer` implementation does not support `take!`.

Comment: This might be easier to handle using a Java queue instead of core.async:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html

Comment: You can get the elements of the underlying linked list that backs the sliding buffer like this: `(seq (.buf (.buf your-channel)))`. Will this work for you?